# Why do some prayers require you to stand?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, standing-sitting

Is there a significance of standing or sitting while reciting a prayer?

The following prayers require one to stand: baruch sheamar, yishtabakh, shemoneh esrei and aleinu (according to some minhagim).

This is more prevalent during the prayers of Rosh Hoshana and Yom Kippur where you are required to get up every 5 minutes when the ark is opened during hazaras hashatz.

Comment: I'm not sure any prayers *require* you to sit; it's just that if you don't have to stand it's more comfortable to sit.  But if you wanted to stand through the whole thing (like the sh'liach tzibbur probably does), that's ok.  Do you know of requirements to sit?  If not, you might want to adjust your title.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I remember seeing in one siddur where it stated that one must be seated when reciting the berachot of shema. I can't find the source now.

Comment: @ramin standing during Boruch shaomar is al pi ari I think.  My minyan doesn't stand for yishtaba7 or shama3. My minyan stands by Boruch shaomar but it is not required. These are new things added on much later after 7azal. I don't say 3oleinu during the year as well only on myself rosh Hashono. Also there is no standing and opening the oron during the repetition. That is a new addition as well.

Comment: @MonicaCellio there is a Tefillah when one is supposed to sit - Nefilas Apayim.

Comment: @Meir I believe there is machloket about that

Comment: @MonicaCellio some siddurim (Artscroll included) say one should sit when reciting the verses of kedusha (kadosh, kadosh kadosh etc) outside of kedusha, such as in birkot keriyat shema shel shachar, uva l'tzion and in motzaei shabbat maariv.