# What factors went into deciding which parts of the davening require standing?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, standing-sitting

I don't know if there is a general rule that can be applied to which parts of davening require standing. I will focus on weekday Shacharit, for now. Some *tefillot* I can understand why there is a requirement to stand.

I understand the custom to stand for Kaddish as mentioned in Shulchan Aruch that Eglon stood when Ehud told him that he had an important message from G-d. (I'l edit in the source, later, B"N).

What is the reason to stand in these other *tefillot* that are part of (weekday) Shacharit?

**Note:** The list below is based on what I have seen people do in most Nusach Ashkenaz shuls or what has been listed in instructions in most Nusach Ashkenaz siddurim such as Art Scroll and Shiloh. Your specific custom may differ.

- Birkot Hashachar ("Asher Natan Lasechvi...)
- Baruch She'amar
- Mizmor L'Todah
- Shirat Hayam
- Yishtabach / Barchu
- Shemoneh Esreh
- The "long" Tachanun said on Mon. / Thurs.
- Taking out & returning the Torah
- Aleinu

Is there a general rule or characteristic that applies to deciding the parts of *tefillah* that require standing, or are almost each of the above unique (reason)?

Comment: What happened to Chazarat HaShatz?

Comment: Perhaps one does not stand by Shemona Esrei because it is called Amida, maybe is called Amida because we stand.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31197/759

Comment: @GershonGold I'll buy that idea. I'm adding it in.

Comment: When taking out and returning the Torah, standing is a sign of respect for it, like when a rabbi enters a room.

Comment: @DoubleAA Does everyone stand during the entire Chazarat Hashat"z? From what I've seen, most stand until after *Kedusha* then sit for the rest. Some only stand for Kedusha.

Comment: R' Schwab on Prayer, and ArtScroll, say that Shirat Hayam does not require standing; people just do it for convenience.

Comment: @Ypnypn "convenience" for what or whom?

Comment: @DanF He writes that you need to stand for Vayevarech David and Yishtabach, it's a pain to sit down for the one minute in the middle.

Comment: @DanF Standing for Chazarat Hashatz is probably more important than most things on your list... Why is there any need to stand for Aleinu?

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair enough. See the "Note" that I added. I think that should resolve potential "conflicts".

Comment: @Ypnypn So far, it seems that you have a handy resource to help you compose an answer :-)

Comment: @GershonGold I understand that Shemoneh Esreh (Amidah) is similar to being before a king. Therefore, one stands.