# Is there a source for standing during ברכות השחר (from אשר נתן לשכוי through הגומל חסדים...) as many have the custom of doing?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer, standing-sitting

What is the source, (if any), for standing during ברכות השחר (from אשר נתן לשכוי through הגומל חסדים...)?

If citing a source from a Sefer please try to quote the words of the Sefer, rather than just the source location מראה מקום.

Comment: Why do you suspect there might be such a source? "as many have the custom of doing" How do you know that? Have you asked them? You clearly don't need to stand for the blessings before רוקע הארץ על המים since those are blessings for things done before standing up from bed. Perhaps you should instead ask for a source for sitting during those blessings

Comment: @DoubleAA not to justify it, but I was taught to stand for all of them in first grade.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31197/3

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56370

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to standing for Birkat Hashachar, the following sources write that one should stand:

> - Ishei Yisrael 5:14 writes that some have the practice to stand.
> - Piskei Teshuvot 46:3 writes that the Ashkenazic minhag is to stand and a person shouldn't deviate from that practice unless they are sick or old.
> - The minhag to stand is sourced in the Mekor Chaim 46:2 . . .

And Siddur Yaavetz ([prior to Netilat Yadayim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42977&st=&pgnum=55) in the morning) instructs standing for all *b'rachos* in general, unless the subject of the *b'racha* involves a different posture, in which case one should assume that posture instead. This would indicate that one should stand for those *birkos hashachar* that do not specifically refer to an activity that isn't done while standing.

([Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchot_HaShachar) footnote 13)

Comment: I could not find the above sources in their original, therefore i posted them this way instead of leaving this question unanswered. But if someone can post an answer with specific quotes, feel free to do so.

Comment: @WAF thanks! I now suspect that Halachipedia misquotes the siddur?

Comment: There are a lot of layers of citation involved there. You should probably either clarify or take out that particular one.

Comment: @msh210 The Siddur Yaavetz which WAF quoted clearly says that ALL b'racos of praise should be said while standing. ONLY if the b'racha refers to a certain action, then does it depend on wheter the action is done while standing or sitting. Thus he is correct that these b'rachos of praise should be said while standing.

Comment: "the subject of the b'racha involves a different posture" A good example of this is the morning blessing 'Mattir Asurim' which is said on sitting up in bed